# Android Gson throws EBADF when large Strings in Json File

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have a webservice that returns Json files like this:

```
{
    "entries": [{
        "summary": "summary",
        "image_url": "images/1_n00056661-b.jpg",
        "description": "This is the main news",
        "title": "test"
    }, {
        "summary": ";lakdsnvk;",
        "image_url": "images/MedicalIconSetCollection06-512.png",
        "description": ";lkvjdianlf",
        "title": "sl;kajf"
    }, {
        "summary": "SALAM SALMASA SFJASDKFNASDKMASLDFJLASDJFASLDFLDSJFLAdfasdf;laskdc;lkasd;lfkas;ldcasdcasdcasdcasdcsadfasdf;laskdc;lkasd;lfkas;ldcasdcasdcasdcasdcsadfasdf;laskdc;lkasd;lfkas;ldcasdcasdcasdcasdcsadfasdf;laskdc;lkasd;lfkas;ldcasdcasdcasdcasdcsadfasdf;laskdc;lkasd;lfkas;ldcasdcasdcasdcasdcsadfasdf;laskdc;lkasd;lfkas;ldcasdcasdcasdcasdcasdf;laskdc;lkasd;lfkas;ldcasdcasdcasdcasdcsadfasdf;laskdc;lkasd;lfkas;ldcasdcasdcasdcasdcsadfasdf;laskdc;lkasd;lfkas;ldcasdcasdcasdcasdcsadfasdf;laskdc;lkasd;lfka",
        "image_url": "images/2028389_P9dRCW4.jpg",
        "description": "s",
        "title": "test"
    }]
}
```

But when the content of one of the fields is large it throws an error like this:

> java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)

Here is the code for Gson:

```
        InputStream source = retrieveStream(newsUrl);
        Reader reader ;
        try {
            reader = new InputStreamReader(source);
            GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
            Gson gson = builder.create();
            SearchResult result = gson.fromJson(reader, SearchResult.class);
            return result.getNews();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
        finally {
            try {
                source.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
```

The line that throws the exception is this line:

```
SearchResult result = gson.fromJson(reader, SearchResult.class);
```

The weired thing is that when the Strings are small there is no problem in loading the Json file!

Comment: There are a few questions at S.O. describing a similar issue. You should also close `source` -- is it reproducible then?

Comment: Hi. What do you mean by closing source?@LyubomyrShaydariv

Comment: Yes the error is reproducible. Every time the string is large I have the same problem!

Comment: I mean, does it fail to work when you add `finally { source.close(); }` ?

Comment: Yes it fails. I've added `source.close();` and it's still failing.

Comment: did you try for testing purposes `android.util.JsonReader`?

Comment: @pskink No I've not tried `JsonReader` yet

Comment: so try it in an empty loop

Comment: What if you simply consume the input stream completely and do not write to elsewhere (ignoring deserialization completely)? Say, something like `ByteStreams.copy(source, ByteStreams.nullOutputStream())` as if you'd use Google Guava?

Comment: I've trie `JsonReader`. When it reaches the `description=reader.nextString()` it throws the same exception! @pskink

Comment: what if you skip the description?

Comment: It throws the same exception on `reader.skipValue()`! @pskink

Comment: then dump the whole reader to some file: most likely the content is broken and you will see where

Comment: How can I dump it to a file? I don't know how! @pskink

Comment: in a loop, read the data from the `Reader` and write it with some `Writer`, for example `java.io.FileWriter`

Comment: @Navid777 Did you manage to read entire stream not writing it elsewhere? At least it would to peel off some components like Gson, because I don't really believe that it a Gson fault: it's something happening at the reading low level. I'm really curious about the issue and its progress.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv I tried to print the InputStream with this command: `return new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A").next();`. The string returned from server seems to be uncomplete! But when I call the webservice with my browser it works fine!

Comment: @Navid777 Did you try to use the same HTTP headers or even make a raw HTTP URL connection?